# Can't find the closing div tag that messes up the page

Tags: css, layout, html

I have this test page [edited by poster after question was answered] and something in the HTML source is messing it up so that the right column is getting placed underneath the left column.

I keep looking at it in firebug but can't locate the spot where the HTML has a problem.  Any idea what is causing that page to place the right-side column below the left side column?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you describe the correct lay-out? "right column" is not very descriptive.

Comment: You are using very bad HTML and CSS: Inline CSS needs to be placed in a stylesheet; <center> tag is very old; no nice enter/tabbing source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you the tag that is not being closed properly is

```
<div style="float:left; width: 700px;">...yourcontent...</div>
```

I can tell because the footer is being trapped in their.

Comment: Just as a suggestion i would second what @Wouter J said earlier.  You should define a class for 99% of all your inline styles.  I RARELY use inline styles.  The problem with it is that when you decide to change a small look you get to play the ctrl+F game for a couple hours.  If i were you, every major section (say this one) i would make a special ID tag.  So your css would look `#main-content{float:left;width:700px}' then your tag can look like `<div id='main-content'>...</div>`  The nice part about this is its easily expandible!  Plus you can have custom titles for each section

Comment: The custom tags could be done like this `#main-content .title{font-size:16px}` and then your side content `#side-content .title{font-size:12px}`

Answer (score 2):

you need to place the right bar div outside the first div of the parent #layout div

```
<div id="layout">
<div style="float:left;"></div>
<div>YOUR RIGHT BAR DIV</div>

</div>
```

Comment: yeah I get that, but in the current page, I can't find the extra closing tag that is messing up the structure.

Comment: ok..open you code in notepad++..you will find the missing div(it will highlight the divs that have ending div).otherwise it will not

Answer (score 1):

I'm no genius, but there was a comment in the source that said:

```
 <!--  Here you need a closing div tag and the right menu goes up. -->
```

You could try putting it there.

Answer (score 1):

You just misplaced the box. You have to place the div that should float on right (the right menu with donate and stuff) right under

```
<div id="layout" class="yui-t6 content">
```